# Can source code examples be kept in a SQL database while retaining all formatting? If so

Tags: sql, language-agnostic, database-design, code-snippets

Can source code examples be kept in a SQL database **while retaining all formatting** (tabs, newlines, etc.)? If so what data type would be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a `TEXT` type (or `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT` - you get the idea)

Answer (score 1):

A BLOB  type (varbinary) would definitely work, although databases shouldn't mangle text that's stored as varchar either.

Answer (score 1):

The best in Sql Server: nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload this into a blob data type.  SQL 2008 comes with the capability of storing the entire executable file in the database.